# Finding the minimum result of a list of results

Tags: python

Is there a code to define / sort through lists?

Comment: As a improvement, you should return the closest value on the function an delegate the print behaviour to another component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Advanced solution

You can use the `min` function of python with the `key` argument like this:

```py
def find_closest(start_point, remaining_points):
    return min(remaining_points, key=lambda a: distance(start_point, a))
```

#### Basic solution

Because of your specific needs (only loops and if statements), here is another solution. For other people who are not restricted, I recommend using the above solution.

```py
def find_closest(start_point, remaining_points):
    closest = None
    closest_distance = 1000000
    # Better but more advanced initialisation
    # closest_distance = float("inf")
    for element in list(remaining_points):
        dist = distance(start_point, element)
        if dist < closest_distance:
            closest = element
            closest_distance = dist
    return closest
```

##### Explanation

Before going through all points, we initialise the `closest` point to `None` (it is not found yet) and the `closest_distante` to a very high value (to be sure that the first evaluated point will be closer).

Then, for each point in `remaining_points`, we calculate its distance from `start_point` and store it in `dist`.

If this distance `dist` is less than `closest_distance`, then the current point is closest from the current stored one, so we update the stored closest point `closest` with the current point and we update the `closest_distance` with the current distance `dist`.

When all points have been evaluated, we return the closest point `closest`.

#### Links for more information

- `min` function: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/min
- `lambda` function: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i appreciate it greatly!
Unfortunately, we haven't been 'taught' min() and key=lambda so i cant use it in my assignment, hence why I added the line that we can't use 'advanced' codes (otherwise I would have found my answer by just Googling as I saw a similar answer somewhere else haha)

Comment: I edited my answer with a simpler solution with only loops and if statements

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this! Life saver!
If you're able to, could you explain a little bit the way the function is working out to find the closest point? (Just for reference in the future so I can create my own code)

Comment: Are these explanations clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and straightforward solution would be to create a list of results and then corroborate the index with your list of remaining points (because they are inherently lined up). Below is a step-by-step process to achieving this, and at the very bottom is a cleaned-up version of the code.

```py
def find_closest(start_point, remaining_points):
    results = []  # list of results for later use
    for element in list(remaining_points):
        result = distance(start_point, element)
        results.append(result)  # append the result to the list

    # After iteration is finished, find the lowest result
    lowest_result = min(results)
    # Find the index of the lowest result
    lowest_result_index = results.index(lowest_result)
    # Corroborate this with the inputs
    closest_point = remaining_points[lowest_result_index]
    # Return the closest point
    return closest_point
```

Or to simplify the code:

```py
def find_closest(start_point, remaining_points):
    results = []
    for element in remaining_points:
        results.append(distance(start_point, element))
    
    return remaining_points[results.index(min(results))]
```

Edit: you commented saying you can't use Python's in-built `min()` function. A solution would be to just create your own functional `minimum_value()` function.

```py
def minimum_value(lst: list):
    min_val = lst[0]
    for item in lst:
        if item < min_val:
            min_val = item
    return min_val

def find_closest(start_point, remaining_points):
    results = []
    for element in remaining_points:
        results.append(distance(start_point, element))
    
    return remaining_points[results.index(minimum_value(results))]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It was exactly what I was looking for! 
Is there a possibility that within the return remaining_points[results.index(min(results))] theres a way to code around the min code? I can't use that in my assignment unfortunately :(

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. Yes, if you can't use the in-built `min()` function, your best bet is probably to define your own. I edited an example into my answer above.